# attendance or attendees

Tags: word-choice

Let's say I want to distribute written agenda this week to people who will attend a meeting scheduled the next week and I say:

> 1. I circulate the agenda to the attendees of the meeting held next week
> 2. I circulate the agenda to the attendance of the meeting held next week.

1) seems fine to me, but how about 2)?

For example, M-W dictionary defines this word as the persons attending.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%20attendance

By this definition, it seems you can use the sentence 2), but you might find this a bit awkward (or maybe not). If so, I would like to know why it is.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. #3 is my bad

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am interested in the usage of those words and the way to express. Your sentence may draw more information. But if you would like me to withdraw the sentence #3 from my question, let me know.

Comment: Yeah, it is wrong, you can remove it. the one with the attendees is correct, but I would insert "to be" to emphasise it's in the future

Comment: I got it, mplungjan. Inserting "to be" is actually a good way to express future in cases like this, but I often forget it... Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

"Attendee" is always ugly and always unnecessary.  Just say "to those coming to the meeting."  In English the suffix “-ee” almost always refers to the person or thing being acted upon, not the person or thing performing the act.  A trainer trains;  a person being trained is a trainee.  As our checkbooks remind us, the payer pays the payee.

Comment: I agree with you that "attendee" is ugly, but I disagree about what you say about the suffix "-ee." Its meaning really depends on the specific verb.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's too bold a claim. Attendee is not always ugly and not always unnecessary. How would you suggest renaming "Attendees list"? Or rewriting the question "Regarding our meeting tomorrow morning, could you please confirm list of attendees from your side?"

Comment: The OED only lists examples of ***attendee*** from 1961 - and the first one it quotes  comes from Webster's dictionary of that date - hence the OED labels it "chiefly American". But you are quite right - though instead of calling it "ugly" I would describe it as "illogical". It has become an accepted sense - though I agree that it is nonsensical when you consider "payee, trainee, employee, retiree etc" mean respectively "one that is paid, trained, employed, retired". Some people in Britain do not use "attendee" claiming that it can only mean "one who is attended upon". (continued)

Comment: Other illogical usages have arisen in this way. The verb "diagnose" for example is almost universally wrongly used across the English-speaking world these days. People say "Jack has been diagnosed with gallstones". It isn't Jack - it is gallstones which have been diagnosed - as the Oxford English Dictionary makes clear. A more strictly correct expression would be "Doctors have diagnosed gallstones in Jack" - which is the way it is used correctly in other European languages, such as French.

Answer (score 3):

The attendees is the correct one (and not attendants as I initially thought)

> I circulate the agenda to the attendees of the meeting to be held next week

The second is not since attendance is more of a count of attendees

Comment: You may have meant attendees. Attendants might be attending to the attendees' needs.

Comment: Oops. you are correct